# scaling problems in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I am having some scaling issues when drawing diagrams using TIKZ. I have a convex hull. I wish to draw a parabola passing through the first two non-zero vertices of the convex hull (a and b respectively). I calculated the coefficients, so that the parabola passes through the first two non-zero vertices of the  convex hull. Although I made the scale uniform, I am not able to get the desired result.
Here is MWE

```
    \documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.35]
    \draw[draw=none,scale=5](0,0)--(-1.1730,0.9848)--(-1.5,0.8660)--(-1.7660,0.6428)--(-1.9397,0.3420)--(-1.9397,-0.3420)--(-1.7660,-0.6428)--(-1.5,-0.8660)--(-1.1730,-0.9848)--(0,0)--cycle;
    \draw[thick,scale=5,color=black]  (0,0)--(-1.1730,0.9848)--(-1.5,0.8660)--(-1.7660,0.6428)--(-1.9397,0.3420); 
    \draw[thick,scale=5]  (-1.9397,-0.3420)--(-1.7660,-0.6428)--(-1.5,-0.8660)--(-1.1730,-0.9848)--(0,0);
    
    
    \draw[scale=5, domain=-2:2, smooth, variable=\y, red]  plot ({1.48720*\y*\y+2.615340}, {\y});
    
    \node[] at (0.75,0.75) {$0$};
    \node[] at (-5.75,5.5) {$a$};
    \node[] at (-7.5,5.0) {$b$};
    
    \draw[thick,->,,>=stealth] (-11.5,0)--(2,0) node[right]{$X$};
    \draw[thick,->,,>=stealth]  (0,-8)--(0,8) node[above]{$Y$};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

I want something like:
[image]

Comment: Could you draw by hand the desired result?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but the points `a=(-5.75,5.5)` and `b=(-7.5,5)` do not appear to lie on this parabola: if `f(y)=-5.10458y^2-1.00456` then `f(5.5)=-155.418105` and `f(5)=-128.91609`, whereas you would need these to be `-5.75` and `-7.5` for `a` and `b` , respectively.

Comment: The coefficients without scaling would be 1.487208 and 2.615340. So it would be essential scaling of the coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks folks. I resolved it. I was thinking it would be image scaling, not the coordinate system. I plugged in the right coefficients and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to reproduce your images:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  T/.style = {font=\scriptsize, fill=white, inner sep=1pt},% ticks
dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt},
     scale = 2]
% axis
\draw[thick,-stealth] (-3,0) -- (2,0) node[right] {$X$};
\draw[thick,-stealth] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above]{$Y$};
\foreach \i in {-2.5,-2,...,1.5}
    \draw (\i,1mm) -- ++ (0,-2mm) node[T, below] {\i};
\foreach \i in {-1.5,-1,-0.5,0.5,1,1.5}
    \draw (1mm,\i) -- ++ (-2mm,0) node[T,  left] {\i};
% rotated parabola
\draw[domain=0:1.2, variable=\y, 
      red, very thick] (-3,0) -- plot (3*\y*\y-2.5, \y);%- 1.00456
% a and b points on parabola
\node (a) [dot,label=$a$] at (3*0.5*0.5-2.5,0.5) {};
\node (b) [dot,label=$b$] at (3*0.6*0.6-2.5,0.6) {};
% line
\draw   (a) -- ++ (-0.4,-0.3)   node[dot] {} 
            -- ++ (0,-1.2)      node[dot] {} 
            -- ++ (0.4,-0.2)    node[dot] {} 
            -- ++ (0.5,-0.1)    node[dot] {} 
            -- (0,0)            node[dot] {} 
            -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```